# iPhone turns off wifi when Lock Screen Active is a bug or a feature?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, facetime

I'm using iPhone 7, iOS 12.1.4.
Recently I notice that people can't call me via FaceTime me when I lock my iPhone, so it turns out the Wifi is only connected when the screen is on. I googled it a bit:

[WiFi Disconnects when Lock Screen active](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8385954)

[Wifi drops when phone is locked after 10.3.3 update](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8027390)

Some says it's a "feature" designed by Apple (to save battery, even when iPhone isn't in Low Power Mode), thus it can't be fixed, but [some suggest solutions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218354/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-dropping-wifi-connection-when-it-goes-to-sleep) to fix (which doesn't work for me).

So if it is a feature, how can iPhone's users receive FaceTime/Facebook messenger calls, do they have to play with their iPhone all day long to make sure they don't miss any call, is there any official word from Apple?

Comment: Does this also happen on your mobile data network, 3g/4g? in other words, does the problem occur when you turn off WiFi completely ( Settings -> Wifi -> toggle off ) ? Also, are you using a VPN app?

Comment: @Motsel : I don't install a Sim card, I only use Wifi. I'm using VPN app. About:"does the problem occur when you turn off WiFi completely", mmm... If I turn off wifi completely, then normally the wifi won't connect either On Screen or Lock Screen, I don't really understand what you mean in that sentence.

Comment: Okay, most likely the problem is your VPN app. Some VPN's disconnect when the device goes to sleep. 1. Can you test if the problem occurs if you disable the VPN app? 2. Which VPN app are you using?

Comment: @Motsel : I'm using HotspotShield VPN & Kaspersky VPN. Now I try deleting both apps to see if the problem is still there. Thanks for your advice. I'll report soon.

Comment: @Motsel : Thanks, after I delete both VPN apps, the problem is solved now. Turn out it is the fault of the VPN apps. Please post the answer then I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @Motsel - Nice bit of troubleshooting there! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: VPN app disconnects wifi when the iPhone goes to sleep mode.
         (even when the VPN isn't used)

Solution: remove the VPN.

I think another solution is to use a VPN app that uses IKEv2 (Apple's native VPN framework):

For example, ProtonVPN can do this https://protonvpn.com/support/protonvpn-ios-manual-ikev2-vpn-setup/

Comment: Removing VPN is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem on iPhone and iPad. Changing to IKEv2 did not help. Then I discovered my VPN app has an option "Keep VPN on when device is idle." Set that option ON and the problem instantly disappeared.